# Could not find an option named "split-per-abi"

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

Please what version of flutter support the `--split-per-abi` option when building an APK file with `flutter build apk`. I am making use of `Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2` and still can't access that option.
According to the documentation [Preparing an Android app for release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android),

> This command results in two APK files:
>
> ```
> <app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
> <app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
> ```
>
> Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains
>   your code compiled for all the target ABIs. Such APKs are larger in
>   size than their split counterparts, causing the user to download
>   native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s
>   architecture.

How can I make it work?

**EDIT:** It works on `Flutter 1.7.4`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your `<app dir>/android/app/build.gradle` add a `splits` section as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split

A basic configuration would be to add this to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

      // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
      enable true

      // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
      // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.

      // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
      reset()

      // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
      include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

      // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

Then just run the command as the documentation says:

```sh
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Here is the list of supported ABIs:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa

With the config above you should get all supported ABIs

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot! I tried the configuration with the flag and it still gave the same error but running `flutter build apk` with the configuration you provided still generated the APKs for the various architectures.

Comment: That's great... maybe it worked for me with the flag because I'm using Flutter 1.7.4 -dev channel. If that's the case, it should make it to the stable branch sometime soon. But at least it works now for you, that's perfect.

Comment: Yeah! I later noticed the warning at the top of the page stating that the documentation is for `Flutter 1.7.4` :-) . Was going to update the question today. Thanks!

Comment: Right, but even with `1.7.4`, you still need to add the `splits` section for it to work. Feel free to mark the answer accepted if you consider it solves the issue :)

Comment: yeah! I understand that part. Thanks! :-)

Comment: after adding the split snippet, I switched to dev channel and the error is gone...thanks dude :)

Comment: With Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2, I can confirm that after adding @davidcv5 's settings, the line `flutter build apk` created split apk versions, and `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` didn't work